# Miss some of data when upgrade laravel to version 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

when i upgrade my project to version8 some of relational data was losing , data is exist in database but when execute query with new laravel some of data was lost, but this query is worked excellent with older version of laravel with no problem.

---

i have two table one is books and second is writers , relation between this two table is many to many (third table is pivot) . i have a query that return list of books with writers :

```
Book::where('name','like', '%joe%')->with('writers')->get();
```

this query is excellent worked with older laravel version but now when upgrade to new version some of records that have multiple writer not shown in book writers and writers field is []

Comment: Please can you show the code you have and give an example of what it use to do and what it does now.

Comment: @Rwd edit question

Comment: did you try it with query builder? you may try giving the with before where clause.

Answer (score 0):

try this example similar to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships).

```
Book::with(['writers' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%joe%');
}])->get();
```